# Why does FreeRTOS API function xEventGroupSetBitsFromISR cause error when I use it in an ISR?

Tags: microcontroller, adc, msp430, rtos, freertos

I am using FreeRTOS on MSP430 microcontroller and I have an error that occurs when I use API function xEventGroupSetBitsFromISR() inside of ADC interrupt routine.
I have searched online and I saw that I need to go to FreeRTOSconfig.h to set certain flags to 1 so that this API function could work but I don't have these flags in my header file. Could I just add these flags my self?

Here is text that says which flags to set:

> INCLUDE_xEventGroupSetBitFromISR, configUSE_TIMERS and INCLUDE_xTimerPendFunctionCall must all be set to 1 in FreeRTOSConfig.h for the xEventGroupSetBitsFromISR() function to be available.

Comment: Yes, you can add those configuration settings to your FreeRTOSconfig.h file if they're not already there.

Comment: Thank you for the help!